# Adding elements to a stack from other methods

Tags: ruby, shoes

I am attempting to make a text output box so that my program can talk to the user (just like a console with a vertical scroll bar). My approach is to create a slot that adds `para` elements to itself as things are being spit out and delete the oldest `para`. I try to access the stack via a variable like so:

```
@output = stack :width => "15%", :height => "100%" do
  background black
  border gray, :strokewidth => 5 
end
```

Later on,

```
@output{para "wish I could code"}
```

throws an error. Am I not allowed to dynamically alter elements in a stack? What is a better way to create an output text box? Any pointers to solid tutorials would be great. I read the manual and the Ebook but I'm looking for some in depth tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's throwing an error is because you're passing a block to a variable. You need a method: `append`.

```
@output.append do
    para "You're doing great"
end
```

Good luck!

As for pointers:

Best Ruby Tutorial: https://rubymonk.com/
Best Ruby on Rails tutorial: http://www.railstutorial.org/

Shoes is a hard place to start just because you either get the old version (shoes 3) or the buggy version (shoes 4). That said, it's also kind of awesome.

If you're looking to learn programming, and programming ideas, I highly recommend Processing:

https://www.processing.org/

Processing is an easier Java, that's almost as powerful.

It has a super-satisfying GUI (graphical user interface), like Shoes, and while it's slightly more verbose than Ruby, you'll get a good idea of what programming is. The tutorials on the website are **fantastic**!

Just remember to return to Ruby! It's the best.

Comment: I love you. Thank you so much lol. I can't describe to you how stupidly giddy I get when I win these little coding victories. One more question, is my approach totally wrong? Should I just keep stacking paras for the output or is there a built in element I am missing?

Comment: You're approach is fine — I'd probably do the same thing. If you want to have the text run together (instead of on new lines) you could use `append` directly on a para, instead of adding new ones to a stack. (You can also emulate adding para's with just one para by adding `"\n"` [a newline] to the end of every string you append.) And I completely understand the giddiness :)